# How can I access an item from an array dynamically with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dynamic

I've got an Array that I'm using to populating the rows of a UITableView.

After a row is selected I need to retrieve information from the Array based on the row selected to populate some outlets (labels, textfields, etc.)

For example:

I create an itemSelected variable in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in my ViewController for the TableView which I set to indexPath.row

```
itemSelected = indexPath.row
```

Then in my viewDidLoad for my otherViewController I need to retrieve the info by

```
array[itemSelected]
```

But, I get a compiler error that says: "Expression resolves to unused i-value"

Comment: You'll want to send a reference to the object to the next view controller in the prepareForSegue method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In here you simply accessing the array but not calling any value. As a example if you have a key call "Name" in your array and you want to set it to a UILabel just do it as this.

```
self.Name.text = array[itemSelected].valueForKey("Name") as! String
```

if not just do something with it.

```
self.Name.text = array[itemSelected] as! String
```

OR

```
print(array[itemSelected])
```